# build alljoyn sample chat failed on android

Tags: android-ndk, chat, alljoyn, ndk-build

I want to use the NDK to build the sample application chat (cpp version) of alljoyn on android. But I got the error undefined reference to 'typeinfo for ajn::BusObject'. And I have checked the alljoyn library path and I could find the libajdaemon.a and liballjoyn.a. The NDK version is r9c. The alljoyn android SDK version is 3.4.6. Can someone help me? Thanks!

The detail information is following:
/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wshu_cn/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libChat.so -shared --sysroot=/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wshu_cn/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-17/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/Chat/Chat_jni.o ./obj/local/armeabi/libstdc++.a -lgcc -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -L/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wshu_cn/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wshu_cn/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib -L../..//lib -L/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wshu_cn/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi -L/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wshu_cn/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi -L./libs ../..//lib/BundledDaemon.o -lajdaemon -lalljoyn -llog -lz -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lc -lstdc++ -lgcc -lgnustl_static -lstdc++ -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi/libChat.so
/Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wshu_cn/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/Chat/Chat_jni.o: in function typeinfo for ChatObject:Chat_jni.cpp(.data.rel.ro._ZTI10ChatObject+0x8): error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for ajn::BusObject'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status